# Did Harper Lee intend Go set a Watchman to be published?

Tags: harper-lee, to-kill-a-mockingbird, go-set-a-watchman

Despite sharing many of the same characters, the books *Go set a Watchman* and *To Kill a mockingbird* portray the same characters in very different ways. I am also made suspicious of how old Harper Lee was when the book came out, as it seems very odd to me.

**Did Harper Lee intend to publish *Go Set a Watchman*?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If one would believe Joe Nocera, former op-ed columnist for *The New York Times*: **No.**

In an article titled [*The Harper Lee ‘Go Set a Watchman’ Fraud*](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/07/25/opinion/joe-nocera-the-watchman-fraud.html) (July 24, 2015 - the book was published on July 14, 2015), Nocera claims that this is a money grab from Lee's current protector, Tonja Carter.

[*Harper Lee: The Sadness of a Sequel*](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/02/the-tragedy-of-harper-lee/385132/) (February 3, 2015) in *The Atlantic* notes:

> Harper Lee, née and known to those close to her as Nelle, spent the
>   majority of her life not wanting *Go Set a Watchman* to be published.
>   Or, at least, she has spent the majority of her life telling the media
>   that she didn't want *Go Set a Watchman* to be published.

This isn't the first instance of controversy after Carter took the reigns. A biography of Lee by Marja Mills also ran into trouble. [*How Unauthorized Is the New Book About Harper Lee?* from Gawker](http://gawker.com/how-unauthorized-is-the-new-book-about-harper-lee-1605214844) (July 18, 2014):

> Things formally went sour in 2011. It was a transition year for the
>   aging sisters, for one thing. Alice Lee, who had practiced law past
>   her 100th birthday, finally retired in December and went into a
>   nursing home herself after a bout of pneumonia. It seems clear that
>   over the course of the year she'd been handing off the reins of her
>   law firm to a younger partner, Tonja Carter.
>
> Earlier that year, in April, Mills had finally sold her book. When the
>   sale was announced, Penguin Press (an imprint at Penguin Random House)
>   described the book as having been written with the participation of
>   both Lee sisters. But shortly thereafter, that same month, a statement
>   bearing Harper Lee's name reached the press:
>
> > Contrary to recent news reports, I have not willingly participated in
> >     any book written or to be written by Marja Mills. Neither have I
> >     authorized such a book. Any claims otherwise are false.
>
> Mills seems to have been caught off guard by this. She already had in
>   hand a statement from Alice Lee dated more than a month earlier, in
>   which Alice confirmed both her participation in the project and her
>   sister's.

Alice Lee passed away about 8 months before *Go Set a Watchman* was published.

All said and done, it looks very fishy.